# код работает в местной песочнице, но не работает на локальном сервере и на jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

при клике на кнопку смена слайда происходит на миллисекунды, затем снова возвращается к первому слайду. при чем по SetInterval все работает, как нужно. в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить? ссылка jsfiddle.net/dglushkov/g7y5p4aj/17

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide '),
     nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

  function Slider(images) {
   this.images = images;
   let i = 0;

   this.next = function() {
    
    this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
    i++;
    
    if(i >= this.images.length) {
     i = 0;
    }

    this.images[i].classList.add('showed');
    
   }

  }
   
  let slider = new Slider(images);

  nextBtn.onclick = () => {
   slider.next();
  }

//  setInterval(function(){
//   slider.next();
//  }, 1000);
```

```css
.wr {
  position: relative;
}
slider {
 width: 768px;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.slide {
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}

.showed {
 opacity: 1;
}

.next {
position: relative;
top: 410px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>

 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slide showed"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас стоит вызов кнопки в теге `<a>` что, в свою очередь, вызывает перезагрузку страницы. 
Воспользуйтесь таким решением:

```js
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide '),
        nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

    function Slider(images) {
        this.images = images;
        let i = 0;

        this.next = function() {

            this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
            i++;

            if(i >= this.images.length) {
                i = 0;
            }

            this.images[i].classList.add('showed');

        }

    }

    let slider = new Slider(images);

    nextBtn.onclick = function(){
        slider.next();
    }
```

```css
    .slider {
        width: 768px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .slide {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .slide {
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .showed {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="next">next</div>
<br>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide showed"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/890x400" alt=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x400" alt=""></div>
</div>
```